# Premiere Pro CC: Multiple instances of a panel in the workspace?

Tags: premiere, adobe

I've worked with Premiere Pro for a while now and created my own workspace based on the panels I need most frequently. I have but one problem: I would like to have multiple instances of the Effect Cotrols Panel within my workspace. This is possible with the Project Panel, however I couldn't find an option to multiply other panels. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this in Premiere in my experience. As far as I know, the only panels you can have multiple of are the Project and Sequence panels.

Comment: Accepted. Don't like it, but at least I know that it's not possible now. Well, maybe Adobe will add that feature sometime ... thanks anyway °v°

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for what purpose did you need multiple Effects panels?

Comment: Well I generally like my workspace, however sometimes the Effect Settings panel is to small for acurate adjustments. In this case, I need to drag it somewhere else or expand it, which becomes quite a bother over time. So I wanted to have two instances of the panel, one larger than the other, so that I could use whichever seemed fitting ...

Comment: Hmmmm...yeah, that's a good point. The only thing I can think of is to have 2 different workspaces, one with the big Effects Settings and one with the small Effects Settings, and just switch between them as needed, though admittedly this is a bit obnoxious.